# Add MENU_CALLBACK to site node in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I have a callback set up in my hook_menu in Drupal 7.

```
$items['interns'] = array(
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'title' => 'Internship',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'page callback' => 'get_current_interns',
  );
```

It renders a page with PHP accessing the taxonomy displaying all current interns working for our company with pictures and all.

I also have a site node containing mostly text. Now I want to combine both - the text site displaying unterneath the content PHP created in the callback.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you setup you page callback but to render fields from a node in D7 you just need to load the node object by id and access the desired field. Something like:

```
$site_textnode = node_load($nid);
// field_name is where your text is stored.
$field = field_get_items('node', $site_textnode, 'field_name');
$output = field_view_value('node', $site_textnode, 'field_name', $field[$delta]);
```

Then combine that with existing output.